# process that works outside the function doesn't work inside the function R

Tags: r, function

I don't understand why this process that works outside the function doesn't work inside the function

First some data:

```
add.variable.to.list <-  function () {
  data <- dplyr::lst(!! variableName :=  dplyr::lst(ICD10, ICD8, ATC))
  VariableDefinor <- append(VariableDefinor, data)
  return(VariableDefinor)
}

# Initiate variable super list
#smoking marker
  ICD10 <- paste("^", c("DF17", "DZ720", paste("DJ", seq(40,44,1), sep = ""), "D716"), sep ="")
  ICD8 <- c()
  ATC <- c("^R03", "^N07BA")
  variableName <- c("smokingMarker")
 
VariableDefinor <- dplyr::lst(!! variableName :=  dplyr::lst(ICD10, ICD8, ATC))

#obesity
  ICD10 <- paste("^D", c("E65", "E66", "E68", "E68"), sep = "")
  ICD8 = c() 
  ATC = c()
  variableName <- c("obesity")

 
VariableDefinor <- add.variable.to.list()
```

What I want to put in a function:

```
unlist(flatten(VariableDefinor$obesity))
```

This outputs: `"^DE65" "^DE66" "^DE68" "^DE68"`

My best version of a function that would allow me  to do this in a general manner:

```
variable.selector <- function (variableList, variableName) {
  
unlist(flatten(variableList$variableName)) #combines sublists to single character vector

  }

variable.selector(variableList = VariableDefinor, variableName = "obesity")
```

Please I would greatly appreciate beyond help with this, if you can point out what it is that I don't understand so I can do it myself next time!

Comment: Try `variableList[[variableName]]`.

Comment: This works @Limey - I just still don't get what it is I don't understand about function inputs and how they are used inside the function.

Comment: It has nothing to do with whether you're inside or outside of a function.  It's a feature of the R language.  See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing) for details.  Note the part that reads ""The form using `$` ... allows only a literal character string or a symbol as the index. That is, the index is not computable: for cases where you need to evaluate an expression to find the index, use `x[[expr]]`.